# How to send a Get request to WCF service with complex parameter?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I am porting a SOAP WCF service to REST. So far, I found out that receiving a complex type as a response does not require pretty much anything. However, my problem is that the request is complex type also. It has 2 fields, one of them is string, the other is a list of another complex type.

I thought to make it WebGet because its basically a search method which asks for certain parameters and returns the resuls.

How should I go about doing this ? What is/isn't recommended ?

Note that I do not have much experience in WCF, apologies if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: discard WCF.  Use ASP.NET MVC WebApi

Comment: have you considered using a post to submit the complex type? i believe it is possible to send a complex, but not advised for the get verb. this link should help you out some http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/more-complex-rest-requests.html

Comment: @Jonesy: Its not my project, I have no choice in what technology to use.

Comment: Use POST instead of GET

Comment: @ermagana POST isn't very REST.

Comment: @Aron are you referring to the suggested implementation? POST is an HTTP verb which lends itself to REST...

Comment: @xander it may be easier to provide suggestions if you could provide more details or an example of your current implementation vs what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @ermagana what I basically have is something like ComplexType GetData(ComplexType searchFilter). GetData then passes searchFilter as-is to another class which does the actual work. I can not make any changes to the format as I do not "own" anything outside my class.

Comment: @ermagana POST is generally considered to produce a change on the webserver, in many instances, not idempotent. GET is generally considered to be a query that generates no change on the server, and is deterministic AND idempotent.

Comment: @Aron I agree with you on the general intent of the verbs you defined, my answer provided below is targeted based on xander's input, two comments above. Sending the complex parameter through the url in a GET request may exceed the url length limit, in addition the method xander refers to takes the parameter and passes it off to another method which does the actual work. A step towards REST for this instance and method may be more of an RPC approach until xander can identify a way to break down the complex type into it's resource endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conform to REST conventions but keep the same request structure, you're probably going to have to serialize the complex type array, url encode it, and pass it as a parameter. This will probably generate very long URLs, which could be a problem. Using POST is more practical, but as @Aron notes this is not consistent with REST, since POST should only be used for updates, not queries.

Instead of trying to copy the SOAP request structure, I'd suggest you think about what this service is doing and re-conceive the input options in a way that can neatly fit into parameters. If you're exposing this interface to 3rd parties, they're going to be baffled by the array of complex types regardless of how you express it.

Comment: Or maybe the functions of the service don't lend themselves to becoming operations on resources.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your feedback and considering your constrained by the fact that you have no control over the class that does the actual work, here it's my suggestion:

Use a post to that endpoint, the complex query. It's true that it's not following the letter of rest, but it's a step closer to utilizing https verbs and no one should knock you for it.

You should also consider defining separate endpoints for the methods in the old SOAP architecture, less points of failure. This approach is closer to an RPC, remote procedural call, but that is better than a POX, plain old xml which is what SOAP is.

Hope this helps, by the way if you read Fielding's dissertation on REST, you're not fully REST until you also implement Hypermedia, but that's an opinionated subject.